# How to change to view helper method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I am working on a app where you can add task etc. I know this is kind of weird but I just like to see how others would implement this. How would you change the following code into a helper method and use it?

The original code

```
<h2>My Tasks</h2>
<% task = @work.tasks %>
<% if task.empty? %>
  <%= link_to 'Create a new task', new_task_path %>
<% else %>
  <%= render :partial => 'notes/note', :locals => {:note => @note} %>
<% end %>
```

My way of doing a helper method

```
def task_check
  task = @work.tasks 
  if task.empty? 
    link_to 'Create a new task', new_task_path
  else 
    render :partial => 'notes/note', :locals => {:note => @note} 
  end 
end
```

In my view

```
<%= @work.task_check %>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally, I wouldn't extract this out at all, this is view logic and it belongs in the views. It definitely doesn't belong in a model, but it could arguably be extracted into a helper. I'd change it slightly:

```
<h2>My Tasks</h2>
<% if @work.tasks.blank? %>
  <%= link_to 'Create a new task', new_task_path %>
<% else %>
  <%= render :partial => 'notes/note', :locals => {:note => @note} %>
<% end %>
```

Calling `blank?` instead of `empty?` will work even if `@work.tasks` is `nil`

.

Answer (score 1):

You can't define a helper in the model. It won't have access to `render`, `link_to` or any other controller or view methods. So just define your method almost exactly as is in a file in your `helpers` directory, maybe `application_helpers.rb` or `work_helpers.rb`:

```
def task_check(work, note)
  task = work.tasks 
  if task.empty? 
    link_to 'Create a new task', new_task_path
  else 
    render :partial => 'notes/note', :locals => {:note => note} 
  end 
end
```

And then call it in your view like so:

```
<%= task_check(work, note) %>
```